# How to get event list programmatically in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, event-observer

i want  list of event in magento.I want a script, whenever it will run get list of events,which is belong to magento...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the commandline you can run `grep -RHin 'dispatchEvent' .` from the `app/code` directory. This will output a list of all locations where an event is triggered.

As you indicated you're working on Windows and you want to do this using a php script. In that case check out this thread on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860393/recursive-file-search-php) on recursive file search. You will need to read each file you find search for `dispatchEvent`. This script will be very heavy to run on the server and should probably not be used in any production environment.

Comment: Thanks ,sander.but i need a php  script which will give me  list of events

Comment: you can use `shell_exec` to run the command and catch the output from a PHP script. Using a Linux command to do this will be a lot faster then using some PHP function that greps through all the files

Comment: Hello @Sander,But i am using window system,I have no knowledge about shell .Thanks Sander

Comment: I've updated my answer